# How to read input matrix of a Matlab mex function row-wise?

Tags: matlab, mex

I need create a Matlab mex function that will take an input matrix and return the matrix diagonal.

Input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 5 6
```

My problem is that since Matlab reads matrices column-wise instead of row-wise, my mex function gives the wrong output.

Current output:

```
1 4 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 5 0 0
0 0 0 0 3 6
```

How would you go about changing my code to read the input matrix row-wise so I can have the proper output?

My code is as follows:

```
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
        mxArray *a_in, *b_out;
        const mwSize *dims;
        double *a, *b; 
        int rows, cols;

        // Input array:
        a_in = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);

        // Get dimensions of input array:
        dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
        rows = (int) dims[0];
        cols = (int) dims[1];

        // Output array:
        if(rows == cols){
            b_out = plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows, rows*cols, mxREAL);
        }
        else{
            b_out = plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(cols, rows*cols, mxREAL);
        }
        // Access the contents of the input and output arrays:
        a = mxGetPr(a_in);
        b = mxGetPr(b_out);
        

        // Compute exdiag function of the input array
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<cols;j++){
                if(rows == cols){
                    b[rows*count+count/rows] = a[j + rows * i];
                    count++;
                }
                else if(rows < cols){
                    b[cols*count+count/rows] = a[j + cols * i];
                    count++;
                }
                else if(rows>cols){
                    b[cols*count+count/rows] = a[j + cols * i];
                    count++;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just transpose the input?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loops, `i` is the row index and `j` is the column index. You do `a[j + rows * i]`, mixing up the two indices. MATLAB stores data column-wise, so you need to do `a[i + rows * j]` to read the input matrix correctly.

For indexing the output, you want the row to remain `i`, and you want the column to be `i * cols + j`:

```c
b[i + rows * (i * cols + j)] = a[i + rows * j];
```

---

Note that you don't need to do `a_in = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0])`, since you are not writing into `a_in`. You can directly access the `prhs[0]` matrix, or do `a_in = prhs[0]` if you want an alias.

Also, casting array sizes to `int` will cause trouble if the array is very large. It is best to use `mwSize` and `mwIndex` for array sizes and indices.

Finally, you should always check the type of the input array, if you are given an array that is not doubles, you will likely cause a read out of bounds error.

---

This is my code:

```c
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
   mwSize const* dims;
   double *a, *b;
   mwSize rows, cols;
   
   if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[0])) {
      mexErrMsgTxt("Input must be doubles");
   }
   
   // Get dimensions of input array:
   dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
   rows = dims[0];
   cols = dims[1];
   
   // Output array:
   plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows, rows*cols, mxREAL);

   // Access the contents of the input and output arrays:
   a = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
   b = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
   
   // Compute exdiag function of the input array
   for (mwIndex i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (mwIndex j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
         b[i + rows * (i * cols + j)] = a[i + rows * j];
      }
   }
}
```